# Parse.com -> Creating new user through CloudCode

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to create new users with random passwords through cloudCode, but I always get an error. The error's body is the password I set.

Here's my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('account', function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.setUsername(request.email);
  user.setPassword(randomString);
  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(newUser) {
      response.success('Hooray');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

What I get as an error is: `b.Error {code: 141, message: "{"password":"tnm3rf6r"}"}`

Can anyone help ?

I've already tried placing `useMasterKey()` outside of the function, inside, right before the signUp, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my mistake.

You have to call `request.params.parameterName` and not just `request.parameterName`.

Silly Mistake.